# tar “Cannot stat: No such file of directory” when passing array variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, tar, array

I'm trying to write a bash script that will create an archive (tar) of files in a directory. The file extensions need to be passed in as arguments when calling the bash script (./backup.bash pdf txt bak) like so. I'm using the array to store those arguments. The (ls | grep -i {array}) is looking up all the files in the directory that match the file extensions entered into the array and will list the files found. the (find . -type) is using those extensions to find files associated with the extensions. The (tar cvf) is creating the backup file in the working directory with the name backup.tar. I listed the array at the end of the tar command, but thinking of it now maybe I could pipe the find command into the tar command.

```
my_array=([$@])
ls | grep -i \{my_array[$@]}
find . -type f \( -name "my_array[$@]" \)
tar cvf ./PATH/backup.tar my_array[$@]
```

Comment: You need to explain ***a lot** more clearly* what you are trying to do.  Almost nothing you’ve posted is a valid command.  You might really need to work one line at a time: what do you want/expect it to do, and what *does* it do?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues in solving this problem.  You need to find all files that have certain filename suffixes, given by a user, and you need to add them to a `tar` archive.

The `find` command has a `-name` option that you rightly want to use, but it can only take a single filename pattern.  Since the user of the script is giving us multiple filename suffixes, we would have to use as many `-name` options as there are suffixes.

This means that we have to construct an array of several `-name "PATTERN"` options, with `-o` in-between each (signifying a logical "OR" between them).  This would then be used with `find` to search for filenames with any of the given filenames suffixes.

The following does that by modifying the array `$@`:

```
#!/bin/sh

for suffix do
    shift
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$suffix"
done
shift    # remove the very first "-o" from $@

find . -type f \( "$@" \)
```

This modifies the `$@` array which, from the start, already contains the suffixes given on the command line.  In the loop, we remove the front element from `$@` and insert our words at the end of the array.

If calling this script as

```
sh script.sh sh txt c
```

it would construct a `find` command that would be equivalent to

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.c' \)
```

This finds all relevant files.  Now we just have to add them to the archive.

With GNU `tar` (but not with e.g. BSD `tar`), the `r` action allows us to *update or create* an archive (BSD `tar` only updates but will not create a new archive).

```
backup=./PATH/backup.tar
rm -f "$backup"
find . -type f \( "$@" \) -exec tar -r -v -f "$backup" {} +
```

This would create the archive `./PATH/backup.tar` with the relevant files.

The reason I don't use `tar -c` is that when we call `tar` from `find` like this, `tar` may be called more than once.  If I used `tar -c` to create a fresh new archive, that archive would be truncated each time `tar` was called (which may be many times if `find` finds many thousands of files).  Using `tar -r` instead, we just keep updating the archive instead.

So, the complete script wold possibly look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

backup=./PATH/backup.tar

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'No filename suffixes given' >&2
    exit 1
fi

for suffix do
    shift
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$suffix"
done
shift    # remove the very first "-o" from $@

rm -f "$backup"
find . -type f \( "$@" \) -exec tar -r -v -f "$backup" {} +
```

Note that the use of quotes in the above script is quite deliberate. It will make it possible to archive files with any allowed filename, including names that contains spaces, newlines and other unusual characters.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

If using a `find` implementation that has `-print0`, you may also pass the found pathnames to GNU `tar` as in the script below:

```
#!/bin/sh

backup=./PATH/backup.tar

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'No filename suffixes given' >&2
    exit 1
fi

for suffix do
    shift
    set -- "$@" -o -name "*.$suffix"
done
shift    # remove the very first "-o" from $@

find . -type f \( "$@" \) -print0 | tar -c -v -f "$backup" --null -T -
```

With `-print0`, `find` will output nul-delimited pathnames that GNU `tar` will read with its `--null -T -` options.

---

That last script as a `bash`-specific script (using an array, `names` for the `-name` options):

```
#!/bin/bash

backup=./PATH/backup.tar

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 'No filename suffixes given' >&2
    exit 1
fi

names=( -name "*.$1" )
shift
for suffix do
    names+=( -o -name "*.$suffix" )
done

find . -type f \( "${names[@]}" \) -print0 | tar -c -v -f "$backup" --null -T -
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh` and GNU `tar` or `bsdtar`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
output=file.tar.gz
printf '%s\0' **/*.(${(j:|:)~${(b)@}})~$output(D.) |
  tar --null -cf - -T - | xz > $output
```

- `${(b)@}`: quotes the positional parameters to prevent them from being taken as patterns
- `${(j:|:)...}`: joins the resulting words with `|`
- `${~var}`: treats expansion as a globbing pattern (now looking like `jpg|gif|\*` if the positional parameters were `jpg`, `gif`, `*`)
- `**/`: any level of subdirectories
- `pattern~$output`: exclude the output file itself from the glob expansion
- `(D.)`: glob qualifiers: include hidden files and only select regular files.